# What are the alternatives of join in MongoDB 4.0 except $lookup operator as it does not work on sharded collections

Tags: mongodb, join, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoid

For example, I have a library database with the following schema.

[image]

And I want the result set as the following dataset.

[image]

What are the ways/queries to get the desired result set but I don't want to use the "$lookup" operator because it does not work on the sharded collection?

Comment: You need to query each collection separately and assemble your results.

Answer (score 0):

`$lookup` is the only option to join two collections in MongoDB.

The other option what I can think of is to convert multiple collections into a single collection.